# How to use the File API to store text data in the samsung TV?

Tags: session, fileapi, samsung-smart-tv

How to use the File API to store text data in the samsung TV ?
And the data  will "live" until the application uninstalled.

I implemented video api of samsung tv. When start my api, asking for user login account. But, I want to store user's login details. User don't need to enter every time login credentials. If once user logged in, and next time username and password should pre populated with details. I think file api is useful for me. But don't understand how to use it. Where to store file which is going to use or what should be extension? And how to access that file fileSystemObj.openCommonFile(curWidget.id + '/testFile.data', 'r');

what is this "curWidget.id" I mean how to use it for my app?

Please, guide me. Or if possible provide me an example.

Answer (score 1):

curWidget.id is widget id of the app in the widgetlist.xml is written widget id.

I hope it is helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

`curWidget.id` is identificator of installed widget, it is provided by smart hub. When you publish your app, it is generated by seller site.

Basic guideline about files: your app should create directory for its files. Recommened path is value of `curWidget.id` property.

Example available in Samsung documentation: http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=tec00111&FileName=index.html

```
var fileSystemObj = new FileSystem();
if (fileSystemObj.isValidCommonPath(curWidget.id) == 0){
    fileSystemObj.createCommonDir(curWidget.id);
}

var jsFileObj = fileSystemObj.openCommonFile(curWidget.id + "/data.dat","w");
/* Some code */
fileSystemObj.closeCommonFile(jsFileObj);
```

Your files will stay and after app uninstallation. You will have to remove them yourself. This is also covered in guide.